# Add id to url wont work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two model less views.

An index view:

```
<% @icd1.each do |f| %>
 <%= link_to "#{f.von}  #{f.bis} #{f.bezeichnung}", icd_show_path(f) %>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

And an show view:

```
<% @icd1.each do |f| %>
  <%= link_to "#{f.von}  #{f.bis} #{f.bezeichnung}", icd_show_path(f) %>
  </p>
  <% f.icd2.each do |s| %>
    <%= s.von %><%= s.bis %><%= s.bezeichnung %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
class IcdController < ApplicationController
  def index
@icd1 = Icd1.all
  end
  def show
@icd1 = Icd1.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

But somehow the link in the index view, wont work:

```
<%= link_to "#{f.von}  #{f.bis} #{f.bezeichnung}", icd_show_path(f) %>
```

When i try to access the show page i get the error:

```
Couldn't find Icd1 without an ID
```

and the url only shows

```
http://localhost:3000/icd/show
```

without an id!

My routes:

```
get "icd/index"
get "icd/show"
```

Comment: Would you add the full backtrace of your error, please, and highlight the line on which the error occurs?

Comment: My url only shows http://localhost:3000/icd/show

Comment: you better put the routes file

Comment: But does the error display in the browser show a trace of lines in your code leading to the error?

Comment: Error in show page line 6, second </p>

Comment: Sorry, I was confused: it's a matter of the output generated by Icd#index for the icd_show_path. Does your Icd1 object have an id? Could you post the code for the Icd1 object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st**: Very confusing naming: controller `icd`, model `icd1`..

---

**2nd:**

```
get "icd/show/:id", to: "icd#show", as: "icd_show"
```

or

```
get "icd/:id/show", to: "icd#show", as: "icd_show"
```

depends what url you want to get. It is confusing.

but I think this is what you need in your url;

```
<%= link_to "#{f.von}  #{f.bis} #{f.bezeichnung}", icd_show_path(f) %>
```

and also the routes:

```
get "icd/:id", to: "icd#show", as: "icd_show"
```

after this next url will be available:

`../icd/1` that will call action `show` from `icd` controller

Comment: Oh yeah, you really helped me a lot! Actually im learning rails, but with this problem i was stuck for hours!

Comment: you have to read about naming conventions, your model as you named it `icd1` might give you problems using it later, I already can't think how you'll add it as resource in your routes file.